# Sending at commands to mobile phone

Tags: nokia, at-command

I try to find library which may make a call from mobile phone and receive status of answer(answered, busy, missed etc.) Mobile phone will be Nokia 6300 or any other which will more optimal for this target. Phone will be connected through USB. The ideal solution  - is cross-platform library (but distribution platform will Windows). I glad to get any suggestions how to solve my goal including sending AT commands.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about voice calls, right? For just the basic functionality you can look at the response from `ATD` and use [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/), e.g.

```
C:\>echo ATD123456890; | atinout - COM14 -
OK
C:\>
```

for a successfully answered call, and with `BUSY` instead of `OK` for a busy call, and not answered I think will return `NO CARRIER`.

Now, I have not tested atinout with a modem on windows, so I do not know how well this works, but I know it compiles fine with both cygwin and mingw, but the cygwin compiled binary seems not to be able to open a com-port properly, so try first compiling with mingw. By all means report success/failure on this.

For additional call progress information, I think there is some newer command specified in the latest versions of 27.007 for this which is unlikely supported by your phones, but `AT+CIND` is probably supported and you might also get some useful information from `AT+COLP` and similar commands.

Comment: ATD; command returns me OK and after few seconds NO CARRIER even if user answered on call. And I dont understand how I can apply AR+CIND command because documentation says that commands uses for setting device indicators value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with `at+clcc`.
Currently this is only command I could find to detect whether call was initiated. 
It returns complex string: "1,0,2,.....", so you should start timer task and track third digit: 2 - init the call, 0 - call dropped, 3 - wait signal received (ringing).

check this help http://www.activexperts.com/serial-port-component/tutorials/gsmdial/